# Can I use wildcard on info-plist for Bonjour services

Tags: wildcard, ios14, xcode12, multipeer-connectivity

My apps using bonjour service to conversation with each other via local network.
I am facing a problem on Xcode12 with OS14 device.

A device publish a service with server type name depends on self device IP address
(example: 192.168.33.20 -> _1921683320._tcp)

B device searching a service with service type depends on A device IP address
(example: _1921683320._tcp)

According to apple document..From OS14~

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity

```
Important
Apps that use the local network must provide a usage string in their Info.plist with the key NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription. Apps that use Bonjour must also declare the services they browse, using the NSBonjourServices key.
```

because my service type name is named by local network ip, it is changeable base on local network setting, so I am thinking about to using wildcard to define the service type name.

example: _*._tcp

but seems wildcard is not available on this definition.(I tried it)

I am also thinking about changing the naming method on A device
(example: 192.168.33.20 -> _20._tcp)
and add _1.tcp ~ _255.tcp to info-plist

But if I changed the naming method, B device could not find A device until version up.

Any idea for this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working through the same issue - Bonjour service name is dynamically created based off the iPad name to form a local mesh network. The conclusion that I have came to is **com.apple.developer.networking.multicast** is required for this to function without completely overhauling how all that logic is done. [(More info here)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_networking_multicast)

You will have to request permission from apple by filling out a [form here](https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/networking-multicast). Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

The thing I am finding is, you "might" not be able to use a wildcard, but you can put multiple entries in the plist:

```
Item 0 _multicastapp0-p._tcp  
Item 1 _multicastapp1-p._tcp
Item 2 _multicastapp2-p._tcp
Item 3 _multicastapp3-p._tcp
etc
Item N _multicastappN-p._tcp
```

So for some reason if you are trying to have multiple "Groups" of 8 or have a device have it's own "collection" i.e. be a server and have 3 devices connect to that, you can.

I haven't "fully" tested but I am going to be doing this in my apps, I did test using multiple keys tho, but not fully, no errors...